# What cause the Garbage disposal wire damage showed in the picture?

Tags: repair

I just wondering what cause the wire damage, shortage, burning, or cut? The garbage disposal stopped working, but not sure it is the wire caused the disposal jammed up, or the jammed disposal damaged the wire?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That does look like heat damage. It's possible that if the disposal jammed and the cord was pressed against something that the current draw heated the wiring enough to melt the housing like that.

## UNPLUG THE DISPOSAL AND DON'T USE IT UNTIL THE CORD HAS BEEN REPLACED

Under your sink, in a wet location, having exposed wires is very dangerous. Your disposal may have a replaceable cord-set, which means that you can unscrew this old one from the disposal and install a new one by screwing it in, or, if it doesn't you *might* get away with cutting off the damaged piece and installing a replacement plug. Worst case, you may have to replace the whole disposal.

Comment: Installing a new cord is not or may not be as simple as "screwing it in"  Wire nuts, and a wire clamp is involved.

Comment: Maybe a bit of an over simplification, @AlaskaMan, but one screws the wire clamp open then shut (in most cases), and one screws a wire nut off, then on, so _technically_... I guess unplugging the cord is a pull operation, followed by a push operation, so it's not "screwing it in", but most folk have a handle on that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from the out-of-focus photo, but I'd give equal likelihood to overheating (due to arcing or motor failure) and physical damage. That scuff looks vaguely like what you'd see if a drawer or something pinched the cable or repeatedly rubbed against it.

The bottom line is that it needs to be replaced as the copper conductor looks nicked. Whether the disposal motor is on its way out is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some testing on the disposal. With the breaker off, see if you can rotate the inside plate, use a broom handle or similar item. There is also a reset button on the outside bottom of the disposal, make sure it's pressed in. There should also be a hole in the middle of the outside bottom where you can fit an allen wench, I think a 1/4", to turn and free the plate if it's stuck. Try running the disposal to see if it works. If it does, turn it off and replace the cord. The cord looks like it came in hard contact with something like @isherwood said. It could have been done on a previous disposal replacement. The copper conductor is damaged and needs to be replaced. People reach under their sinks way too often without looking to have something this dangerous lurking around. If the disposal doesn't work, then a replacement will be needed.

Comment: Thank you all! The information is very helpful and appreciated. Cindy